# General Linear Group: Thinking of invertible matrices as bijective functions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, general-linear-group

In my lecture notes I encountered the following result,

> For any set $S$ the set $F$ of bijective functions $f:S\to S$ is a group under composition, but is not in general abelian.

Then it was mentioned that:

> The set of invertible $n\times n$ matrices over field $\mathbb F$ is a group under matrix multiplication: **it is a special case of the above result with $S=\mathbb F^n$ and is non-abelian if $n>1$.** It is called the *general linear group,* $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb F)$.

I am having trouble seeing the connection between the two. How can you think of a matrix as a bijective function when it doesn't have an input? Am I missing something?

Thanks so much in advance :)

Comment: I have difficulty too! It is not a special case since $\text{GL}(n,\mathbb F)$ is definitely not the set of bijective functions from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to itself: it consists of only the linear bijective functions.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Actually that's a good point, I didn't think of that. Do you know whether the result in the first blockquote (bijective functions is a group) is only true if it is *all* bijective functions between $\mathbb F^n$ to $\mathbb F^n$? Could it potentially be subgroup of *all* bijective functions or something?

Comment: More generally on has a set with some "structure" and one gets a group when one looks at the bijections which "preserve the structure". Making this precise in general is tedious, but we are often interested in special cases. For example the bijections of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which preserve the distances form an interesting  group.

Comment: @ancientmathematician
Oh wow that is indeed quite interesting. Does this have anything to do with isomorphisms? (I assume maybe not since you said it's tedious for an accurate general statement). Do linear maps (formed by invertible matrices) also "preserve the structure?"

Comment: "Isomorphism" just means "bijective structure-preserving". Giving "structure" a precise meaning would need more space than we have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important viewpoint is that the whole reason matrices exist is to represent linear transformations. When you think of an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ with entries in a field $F$, you should usually think about the mapping $L_A:F^n \to F^m$ defined by $L_A(x) = Ax$.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Is it a convention to call the matrix $A$ itself as a map, but a general understanding that it is actually $L_A$? Would the above result be more correct by saying that the "linear maps associated with these matrices form a special case of the group of bijective functions?"

Comment: Yes, I think that would be more correct. People do sometimes speak about $A$ as if it were a linear transformation, when really it is $L_A$ that is a linear transformation.

Answer (score 2):

Given any two $\mathbf F$-vector spaces $U$ and $V$, of dimensions $m$ and $n$ respectively, a linear map $f:U\longrightarrow F$ is entirely determined by the images of the vectors $e_i\;(1\le i\le m)$ in a basis $\mathcal B$ of $U$.

These images have $n$ coordinates in a basis $\mathcal B'$ of $F$. Thus one can associate to the linear map $f:(U,\mathcal B)\longrightarrow(V,\mathcal B')$ the $n{\times}m\;$ matrix $A=(a_{i,j})_{\substack{1\le i\le n\\[0.5ex]1\le j\le m}}$, where the $j$-th column is made up from the $n$ coordinates of $f(e_j)$.

In particular, if $U$ and $V$ have the same dimension $n$, we obtain a square matrix (which depends on the chosen basis). It can be shown that $f$ is an isomorphism if and only if this matrix is invertible, i.e. if and only if its determinant is non-zero.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there an intuitive reason why an invertible matrix forms a bijective linear transformation?

Comment: Yes: choose a basis, and represent a vector by the column vector of its coordinates. The inverse matrix is associated to the inverse isomorphism (one checks that the composition of linear maps corresponds to the product of the matrices associated to the linear maps).

Comment: Oh right, so the matrix maps exactly one vector from the domain to the codomain, and the inverse maps that same vector in the codomain to the starting vector in the domain? (So we can sort of visualise a 1-1 and onto mapping?)

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it's exactly so.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of $n\times n$-matrices $A$ over ${\Bbb F}$, one considers the mappings $f_A:{\Bbb F}^n\rightarrow{\Bbb F}^n:x\mapsto Ax$ (matrix-vector multiplication). The mapping $f_A$ is bijective iff the matrix $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is the reason why it's bijective iif the matrix is invertible because "each vector in the domain is mapped to a unique vector in the codomain"?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Is the reason why it's bijective iif the matrix is invertible because "each vector in the domain is mapped to a unique vector in the codomain"?

Comment: Its a bijective mapping. In a function, each element is mapped to a unique image.

Answer (score 1):

The foundation of linear algebra is the matrix representation theorem:

If $U,V$ are finite dimensional vector spaces with bases $(u_1,\ldots,u_n)$ and $(v_1,\ldots, v_m)$, then any linear function $f\colon U\to V$ satisfies:

$$\begin{aligned} f(u) &= f(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_j u_j) &\text{for some $\alpha_i$ since $(u_j)$ are a basis} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j f(u_j) &\text{since f is linear} \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \alpha_j \sum_{i=1}^m \beta_{ij} v_i &\text{for some $\beta_{ij}$ since $(v_i)$ are a basis} \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{m} \big(\sum_{j=1}^{n}\beta_{ij}\alpha_j\big)v_i &\text{rearranging}
\end{aligned}$$

So for any vector $u\in U$ with coordinates $a = (\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$, with respect to the basis $(u_j)$, the coordinates of $f(u)\in V$, with respect to the basis $(v_i)$ are
$$c = \big(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_{1j}\alpha_j, \sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_{2j}\alpha_j, \ldots, \sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_{mj}\alpha_j\Big) = B\cdot a$$

So, when we fix our coordinate system to $(u_j)$ in $U$ and $(v_i)$ in $V$, we can equivalently represent the function $f$ as $$a\mapsto B\cdot a$$

The $B$ matrix contains at entry $ij$ the $i$-coordinate of $f(u_j)$, i.e. it encodes how the basis vectors of $U$ are mapped into $V$ under $f$.

This is the main reason matrices where introduced in the first place: as a useful notational convention to denote linear maps between finite dimensional vector spaces. So a matrix $A$ "is" the linear map $x\mapsto Ax$

Comment: Thanks you for your response! It was insightful to see where background theory comes from. May I ask why we say $A$ is the linear map, and a bijective map when invertible, rather than say $T$ as the bijective map where $T(\mathbf{x}) = A\mathbf{x} $? (That is, the linear transformation associated with the matrix?)

Comment: @user523384 Sorry but I don't understand the question. Not every linear map is bijective. To be injective, we must have $f(u)\neq f(u')$ whenever $u\neq u'$. In particular, since $f(0)=0$ we must have $B\cdot a\neq 0$ for all $a\neq 0$. This means that the columns of $B$ are linearly independent $\iff$ $B$ has full column rank  $\iff$ $\ker B ={0}$. Likewise one can show that $f$ is surjective if and only if $B$'s rows are lin. independent, i.e. if it has full row rank.